# INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE BSOD on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod, bsd

I am getting the error INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE, I have tried everything.the computer is in an infinite loop of restarting.

Safe mode doesn't start, the reset this PC doesn't work, the uninstall updates doesn't work, the system restore doesn't, the system image recovery doesn't work, I have windows on pen drive and it can't find it. The startup repair doesn't work.

My files are still there, I can see on the command prompt. I just cant star windows anyway. 
It for like this sundelly, I am starting to think it's some kind of virus.

Comment: It's way more likely a failing drive.

Comment: @GrabrielaGarcia do you mean a the physical device or software problem?

Comment: I think I will delete everything, including my files and install everything from zero. I need to find a way to keep my files in a different volume.

Comment: Don't forget to check the drive's health before anything else. If it's bad reinstalling is a waste of time.

Comment: I ran CHKDSK and it is showing everything is fine